# Access global variable inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

How to pass a variable as a parameter to a function?

This is my code

```
def hello (arg):
    global my_name
    my_name = "tarek"

    print("my name is " + arg)

hello(my_name)
```

This should print

```
my name is tarek
```

but it doesn't, giving me a NameError, although I declared the variable my_name as global.

Well it works well if I declared the variable outside the function, but why is it not working when declaring the variable inside the function?

Comment: Because the variable isn't defined until after you call the function.

Comment: You do not need a `global` variable either in this code, and `global` variables are a typical source of problems, you should avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your global variable outside of your function, then you don't need to define it again in the function. Following code will print what you want:

```
my_name = "tarek"

def hello(arg):
    print("my name is " + arg)

hello(my_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no variable my_name until the function is called so there is nothing to pass into the function, giving the error.
Define the variable outside the function, then declare it global inside the function, if you must.

If you want my_name to be global you don't need to pass it into the function. Just declare and assign it outside the function, then declare it global inside.

Passing parameters is usually done because you want it to be local to that function, then we usually return it back after its been worked on. Compartmentalising you code helps when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing within `hello()` can make `my_name` exist by the time `hello()`is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable declaration is scoped to inside the method (a closure), and that closure is not evaluated until you invoke it, at which point you get an error because the variable does not exist in that context.

If I understand correctly, it would seem you want to do this

```
def hello (arg):
    global my_name
    my_name = arg

    print("my name is " + arg)

hello("tarek")
```